# Issue with optional request param in POST method

Tags: java, rest, post, optional-parameters, http-request-parameters

I have a POST API as below:

```
@POST
@Path("/api/analysis/s3file/{filename}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response analysis(@PathParam("filename") String filename, @RequestParam(value = "errorDesc", required = false, defaultValue  ="true") String errorDesc) ()
```

However i am unable to fetch the request param 'errorDesc' when i invoke this API like http://localhost:8080/MyApp/api/analysis/s3file/abc.zip?errorDesc=true.

When i print the value of the string errorDesc, i see that its being the value of the request payload (eg: ------WebKitFormBoundaryEu2iBOEbKojgV3wO--)

Could someone help me resolve the issue. I had checked related questions but was unable to identify the issue.

Comment: try changing `String errorDesc` content with `boolean errorDesc`

Comment: @ArvindKatte: Yes, i did try that but no luck.

Comment: Are you using jax-rs or spring as it looks you are mixing annotations from both frameworks - it should be `@QueryParam` for jax-rs instead of `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @user158037 Yes my bad. I realized that i used the wrong annotation sometime back. Thanks a lot!